# Authenticating Apache/SVN via Active Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, svn, ldap

I am absolutely tearing my hair out with this one, largely as a result of not being able to find any real documentation on the topic. My box is ubuntu server, and my repository is fully browsable - I just can't perform a commit. My /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf looks as follows:

```
<Location /svn>

  DAV svn
  SVNPath /svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc0001/OU=Users,DC=dc0001,DC=unifybusiness,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=administrator,OU=Unify,DC=dc0001,DC=unifybusiness,DC=local"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "REDACTED"

  #<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  #</LimitExcept>

</Location>
```

and my rejection from the apache logs looks like this (I have tried authenticating myself as both "adusername" and "domain\adusername":

```
[error] [client 172.16.20.13] user unify\\ahand: authentication failure for "/svn/Misc": Password Mismatch
[error] [client 172.16.20.13] user ahand: authentication failure for "/svn/Misc": Password Mismatch
```

Any pointers someone might be able to offer would be very much appreciated - I am resorting basically to trying random combinations fo adjustments and that is no way to go on.

Answer (score 1):

The [following](http://www.itguyonline.com/blog/2007/05/02/ldap-authentication-for-subversion-on-ubuntu-feisty/) link suggests that you should point your AuthLDAPURL to a Global Catalog server and use the port 3268 and not the standard 389

Also, look at your DC's Security logs, they might give you a clue as to what went wrong on that side.